# jQuery date picker function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a date picker function in jQuery that allows the user to select a date. In the HTML I have some text in a `<p id="dateText">`, which is hidden. I'm trying to allow when the text box is not empty (i.e. a date is selected) to allow the dateText value to show and fade in.
I'm not sure if I can compare html and javascript within a jquery function, I just started learning it a few days ago. Here is what I have for it but it won't work. Thanks in advance.

```
$(function() {
    $("#datePick").datepicker(); // id of text box in html

    if (datePick.value ==="") {
        $("#dateText").hide();   // id of <p> text in html
    }
    else {
        $("#dateText").fadeIn("slow"); 
    }
});
```

Comment: It might help if you `console.log(datePick.value)` before the `if` statement, in order to see if it is exactly the same as "" in the case where you want it to be.

Comment: Your `if` is running when the page is first loaded, _not_ when the user picks something from the datepicker.

Comment: If you want to run something when the user selects a date, put it in the datepicker's `onSelect:` callback.

Comment: Thanks Barmar, I didn't think of the onSelect callback, works fine :) Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to perform a test when the user selects something from the datepicker, put it in the `onSelect` callback function.

```
$(function() {
    $("#datePick").datepicker({
        onSelect: function() {
            if (this.value === "") {
                $("#dateText").hide();
            } else {
                $("#dateText").fadeIn("slow");
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: onSelect is beauty! Thanks again